# Call Nested Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, count, discord

This might have already been covered before but I am having issues calling a nested function for my discord bot. It is meant to count down from 3 to 0 & display outputs to the user at each stage. I have the Async commands working so figured I would just use print to test that's why none of that is visible.

If anyone can see an issue with my code could you please let me know as I'm hitting a brick wall.

```
def count(countfunc):

def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

    wrapper.counter = 3
    wrapper.start = 3

    wrapper.counter -= 1
    if wrapper.counter == 0:
        print(f"has ran out of warnings & is now banned on the server for 1 day")
    else:
        print(f"has", wrapper.counter ,"warnings left")
    return countfunc(*args, **kwargs)

return wrapper("*args, **kwargs")


@count def countfunc(wrapper):
    return
 
print (countfunc)
```

I am trying to call the print values from the wrapper  if statement. This works when called within the count function/wrapper function but when called outside of it just says "None". I'm gathering that this is due to it not being able to read the function values but not 100% sure how to fix it.

Many Thanks In Advance,
Ben